# SQL comparing each row to a reference row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to compare each row from a select statement to a reference row.

So to put it into context I would like to find the reference row which is the account details for one of our users.

```
SELECT id, first_name
FROM account
WHERE id = '100'
```

Would return the info for the user in question

Then I want to run a SELECT statement to return all users - pretty straightforward

```
SELECT id,first_name
FROM account
```

For each row I would like to compare the first_name with the reference row. If it is the same return a '1' if it is different return a '0'

I can do this if I type in the value to compare e.g 'Paul'

```
SELECT id,first_name,
CASE
    WHEN first_name = 'Paul' THEN '1'
    ELSE '0'
END
FROM account
```

But obviously I want to replace Paul with whatever the first_name is from the reference row above.

My googling suggests I need to declare a variable and then something with SELECT INTO a variable

```
DO $$;
Declare
       @reference_first_name   text;
BEGIN
SELECT first_name
into @reference_first_name
FROM account
WHERE id = ‘100’
END;
```

But I can't seem to put it together.

Then to go a step further would it be possible to reference multiple columns?

Comment: Please add some example data and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this simply in a subquery:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=26869f3bdcd7717c30b97b570d476407)

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    first_name, 
    CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT first_name FROM users WHERE id = 100) = first_name THEN 1 
        ELSE 0
    END
FROM users;
```

Other ways are using a CTE or a JOIN (see fiddle for these versions)

Comment: Thank you that is incredibly useful! Do you know if it would be possible to have another column to compare last_name etc. ?

Comment: Of course that would be possible. But please provide your data (e.g. you could expand one of the provided fiddles) and expected data. Would the second column be an AND or an OR comparison?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option using an `outer join`:

```
select a.id, a.first_name, case when a.first_name = b.first_name then 1 else 0 end
from account a
    left join account b on b.id = 100
```

- [Online Demo](https://rextester.com/UMXGY25750)

Comment: Although if you know that the reference row exists, you could use an `INNER JOIN`, no? Also, I would propose using a different table alias for the reference join...something like `LEFT JOIN account AS ref ON ref.id = 100`

Answer (score 0):

Use `correlated subquery` as :

```
select a.id, a.first_name,
        ( select count(*) 
            from personnel p 
           where p.id = 100 
             and upper(p.first_name) = upper(a.first_name) ) as flag
  from account a;
```

provided you have a table called `personnel` and has an ID fixed for all comparisons.

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/EAEOH43501)